# what's your favourite bookmark utility similar to google's bookmark

Tags: windows, bookmarks

Google bookmark is good, but After use it for one year, I found I've bookmarked too many links that to find a certain url becomes not as easy as before . so I'm looking for a even better bookmark utility than Google's bookmark.

Answer (score 4):

As much as this may sound archaic (or worse, *offtopic maybe*), I've found that the best bookmark keeping strategy for me is this: normal firefox (or *insert your flavour here*) bookmarks, until they get too big in numbers. Then export everything to html file, leave only the crucial ones (the ones I visit regularly, like gmail, weather report, SU and such), and start from beginning.

Backup the html file with a date to gmail. Searchable. Very clear to look at. Much clearer than most.

Otherwise from that, I've found [delicious](http://delicious.com/) "acceptable" (but still gave up on it after a while, this being simpler).